# How do I change options in PAM configuration?

Tags: pam

I have an issue that research indicates can be corrected by changing an option in a PAM configuration by running `pam-auth-update`. I've done that, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the options from selected to deselected in the interface presented. Any hints? (I need to disable "SMB password synchronization" if it makes a difference.)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You press the spacebar to select/deselect options, and use the arrow keys to move up and down the list.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out the arrows to move up and down, but couldn't figure out what key I needed to change selection values.

Answer (score 2):

Then I guess you have to use spacebar to uncheck that option by using Up and Down arrow key.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply check inside  /etc/pam.d/ for "SMB password synchronization" If it is there then rename these files. Not finding the file named after the service requesting authentication, PAM will fallback to the (hopefully) very secure /etc/pam.d/other. If you later find that you need one of these programs, you can simply rename the file to its original name and everything will work as it was intended. Hope so it works :)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked. I'm not asking for other ways to do this; I want to know how to deselect the selected option in the interface shown.